# Can I create a shortcut to a command?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

During debug mode, and I select an expression that returns some value.
I can right click and select the 'debug: evaluate' option.

Can I create a command to perform this action? for example <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Try the command:

```
editor.debug.action.selectionToRepl

{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+i",
    "command": "editor.debug.action.selectionToRepl"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can customize keyboard shortcuts via File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts.  See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings.

I believe the shortcut your want is called Debug.EvaluateStatement.